# I cannot delete photo in live server in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am able to delete photo in local xampp server but I cannot delete photo completely in live server

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $employee=EmployeeContract::find($id);
    $employee->delete();
    Storage::delete($employee->photo);
    return redirect()->route('employeecontract.index');
}
```

Comment: did you enter ```php artisan storage:link``` in live server

Comment: @Milan Katwal, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include some more information about your problem such as what error you are getting. Simply telling what is not working for you doesn't really help much.

Answer (score 0):

delete a photo from a folder, before you delete it from DB.

```
$employee=EmployeeContract::find($id);
Storage::delete($employee->photo);
$employee->delete();
```